# What are the correct Android manifest settings for an Adobe AIR application to restrict device availability?

Tags: android, air, adobe, manifest, flashdevelop

I am writing an Adobe AIR Android application using FlashDevelop, and I want to make sure that when I publish it to Google Play it is only available to devices that support Adobe AIR based applications.  What is the proper way to configure this in my project files?

**UPDATE:** 
Tech Requirements for Adobe AIR 3 (from [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html)):

- ARMv7 processor with vector FPU, minimum 550MHz, OpenGL ES 2.0, H.264 and AAC HW decoders
- Android™ 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, and 4.0
- 256MB of RAM
- Android web browser

Comment: fwiw, here is an Adobe page concerning [Android manifest settings for AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html).  It does not answer this question but has other useful related information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AIR will run on Froyo (Android 2.2 SDK version 8) or above. In your application.xml add the following to the manifest additions

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

This will ensure anything running less than 2.2 wont be compatible with your app.

Comment: Will this filter out unsupported ARMv6 devices? (if those can run Android 2.2 at all)

Comment: I dont think there is a way to filter out the unsupported ARMv6 devices. That code will show the app as incompatible on anything less than 2.2

Comment: Thanks!  I've updated the question with the full list of requirements.

Comment: I've just uploaded an application using only the manifest setting you mentioned, and Google Play specified that "This apk requests 1 native platofrms that will be used for Google Play filtering: armeabi-v7a".  So I guess that takes care of itself. :)  Marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

You need to add supports-gl-texture flag to filter out devices with old opengl and video-card:

```
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture"/>
```