# Check device for Adobe Air support

Tags: android, air

I'm building a paid Android app with Adobe Air (Air 3.2 / Flash CS6). How can I make sure that the user's device supports Adobe Air before he purchases my app? Does the Google Play Store take care of this, or is there a programmatic way for me to check (with AndroidManifest settings or otherwise)?

Answer (score 3):

You can bundle Adobe AIR with your app. You get this option when you export your app's APK. That will make sure your app is downloaded with all it needs.

However, that will make your app HUGE (about 30mb more than its real size)

Another option, is to just do nothing, and when the user downloads and installs your app, they will be prompted to install Adobe Air.

This is also an option when you export your App, as you can defined where from you would like users to download Adobe Air.

The reason why it's important to be able to chose where from they download it, is the fact that if you're selling your app through Amazon, you will want to give users the link to Adobe Air on Amazon, where's Google Play will be a different link.

Flash builder is quite helpful on that, and will give you all you need when you try to sign your application.

Answer (score 2):

It actually says if an app is incompatible with your device before you download from the app store. If you wish to check a device yourself, look here: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html

Answer (score 0):

If you include Air the App size is increased by 7.5 Mb.
The compatibility is usually checked by the stores (Google Play and the AppStore do the job right).

Comment: So? should @vincent include Adobe Air or leave to the store the checking?

Answer (score 0):

**To clarify**:

The Play store does not check for compatability based upon the specs defined by Adobe AIR, but rather the meta data you define in your manifest when you compile the application (ie `<supports-screen>`, `<uses-feature ...bluetooth>`, etc.) It is rumored that you can set the `<uses-sdk...>` flag and the Play store will recognize the processor requirement. I have not been able to find any official documentation regarding this however, just this thread here:

[What are the correct Android manifest settings for an Adobe AIR application to restrict device availability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580607/what-are-the-correct-android-manifest-settings-for-an-adobe-air-application-to-r)

If anyone can confirm this it would be greatly appreciated.